# Парсинг html-страницы python. BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Всем привет! Передо мной встала задача по парсингу данных с данной [веб-страницы](https://www.artprice.com/artist/15079/wassily-kandinsky/lots/pasts?ipp=100). На ней представлены данные по работам, выставленным на аукцион. Необходимо получить подчеркнутые красным маркером данные для каждого лота на странице. [image: скриншот] Пытался сделать это с помощью BeautifulSoup и поиску по строкам с помощью регулярных выражений. У меня получилось собрать данные по номеру лота, наименованию картины, странам, названию аукциона и его дате (крайний правый и крайний левый блоки). Сбор данных из центральных блоков вызывает затруднения - не нашел способа сослаться на заключенные в тегах строки. Привожу пример текущего скрипта:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

URL_TEMPLATE = "https://www.artprice.com/artist/15079/wassily-kandinsky/lots/pasts?ipp=100"
FILE_NAME = "test"

def parse(url = URL_TEMPLATE):
    result_list = {'lot': [], 'name': [], 'date': [], 'type1': [], 'type2': [], 'width': [], 'height': [], 'estimate': [], 'hummerprice': [], 'auction_date': [], 'auction': [], 'country': []}
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
    lot_info = soup.find_all('p', class_='hidden-xs')
    date_info = soup.find_all('date')
    names_info = soup.find_all('a', class_='sln_lot_show')
    auction_info = soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')
    auction_date_info = soup.find_all(string=re.compile('\d\d\s\w\w\w\s\d\d\d\d'))[1::2]
    for i in range(len(lot_info)):
        result_list['lot'].append(lot_info[i].text)
    for i in range(len(date_info)):
        result_list['date'].append(date_info[i].text)
    for i in range (len(names_info)):
        result_list['name'].append(names_info[i].text)
    for i in range(0, len(auction_info), 2):
        result_list['auction'].append(soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')[i].strong.string)
    for i in range(1, len(auction_info), 2):
        result_list['country'].append(soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')[i].string)
    for i in range(len(auction_date_info)):
        result_list['auction_date'].append(auction_date_info[i])
    return result_list
df = pd.DataFrame(data=parse())
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Незаполненными остались массивы type1 (что должно соответствовать "Print-Multiple" со скрина), type2 (="Print in colors"), width (75), height (80) и hummerprice (="not communicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

URL_TEMPLATE = "https://www.artprice.com/artist/15079/wassily-kandinsky/lots/pasts?ipp=100"
FILE_NAME = "test"

def parse(url = URL_TEMPLATE):
    result_list = {'lot': [], 'name': [], 'date': [], 'type1': [], 'type2': [], 'width': [], 'height': [], 'auction_date': [], 'auction': [], 'country': []}
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "html.parser")
    lot_info = soup.find_all('p', class_='hidden-xs')
    date_info = soup.find_all('date')
    names_info = soup.find_all('a', class_='sln_lot_show')
    auction_info = soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')
    auction_date_info = soup.find_all(string=re.compile('\d\d\s\w\w\w\s\d\d\d\d'))[1::2]
    my = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-8 col-sm-6')
    for i in range(len(lot_info)):
        result_list['lot'].append(lot_info[i].text)
    for i in range(len(date_info)):
        result_list['date'].append(date_info[i].text)
    for i in range (len(names_info)):
        result_list['name'].append(names_info[i].text)
    for i in range(0, len(auction_info), 2):
        result_list['auction'].append(soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')[i].strong.string)
    for i in range(1, len(auction_info), 2):
        result_list['country'].append(soup.find_all('p', class_='visible-xs')[i].string)
    for i in range(len(auction_date_info)):
        result_list['auction_date'].append(auction_date_info[i])
    for i in range(len(my)):
        all_p = my[i].find_all('p')
        lest = all_p[1].get_text().split(',')
        result_list['type1'].append(lest[0])
        result_list['type2'].append(lest[1])
        try:
            result_list['width'].append(all_p[1].find_all('span')[-1].get_text().replace('x','').replace('cm','').split()[0])
        except:
            result_list['width'].append('')
        try:
            result_list['height'].append(all_p[1].find_all('span')[-1].get_text().replace('x','').replace('cm','').split()[1])
        except:
            result_list['height'].append('')
    return result_list
df = pd.DataFrame(data=parse())
df
df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

В некоторых моментах бывает, что строка пустая, поэтому поставил `try`

Comment: Благодарю за вариант решения проблемы! Только у меня не предустановлен модуль pp, а при попытке установить его через !pip instal pp возникает ошибка. Есть какие-либо альтернативы с её использованием или можно установить другим способом?

Comment: Ох, забыл сказать, что модуль pp это замена для print, чтоб красиво выводить, поэтому можете его просто удалить из кода

Comment: Исправил. В `except` написал так, потому что в некоторых случаях данные с сайта бывают пустыми

Comment: Сработал с внесенными поправками, однако он записывает в каждую строчку таблицы данные последнего лота (для столбцов type1, type2, width, height). Поправил с помощью `append`. Также нашел некоторую особенность в hmtl-разметке: для каждого лота имеется разное количество тегов `<span>` (у некоторых лотов на место [1] span'a встает перевод в дюймы (ng-show="to in")), поэтому поменял индексацию на [-1] (span в сантиметрах всегда последний).

Comment: Кроме того, нашелся проблемный кейс с лотом, в котором отсутствует высота, и в таком случае скрипт на i-й итерации записывает 2 значения ширины: сначала имеющийся, а затем пустой, что приводило к разной длине массивов и не получалось собрать их в таблицу. Поправил это добавлением еще одной конструкции `try` и `except` отдельно для высоты. Корректировки внес в ваш ответ. В целом, вы мне очень помогли, большое спасибо!

Comment: @impoz3v Да не за что) Я не прям спец в питоне, и про эти тонкости не особо знаю, типа `[-1]`)